# Where to find the environment name for business central APIs in dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

I want to explore the APIs that I can use in Dynamics 365.

So I read Exploring the APIs with Postman and the basic authentication document that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-connect-apps#exploring-the-apis-with-postman-and-basic-authentication).

This page is mentioning that the format of the API that will explore the APIs is as follows:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/<your tenant domain>/<environment name>/api/v2.0.
```

using the GET method.

I got the tenant domain and the username and the token of the authentication. However, I have a problem getting the environment name.

Every time I add a new environment in the Dynamic 365, the form asks me to provide an environment link that should be successfully tested. I don't know how to get this link. So the environment part in this URL is not clear for me.

So if anyone can help me with getting the environment I will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods you can use to find out what the environment name is:

1. Business Central Admin Center (`https://businesscentral.dynamics.com/[your tenant domain]/admin`). Here you can find a list of all Business Central environments. Requires that you have admin permissions for Business Central on the tenant.
2. Business Central client. Click the question mark in the top right corner and then `Help & Support`. At the bottom of the page under `Report a problem` you will see both the `Azure AD tenant` and the environment name and type. If you do not have access yourself, you can ask your customer to retrieve the information.